# Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-minify-css'

Tags: gulp, npm

На самом деле модуль gulp-minify-css давно установлен, только версия устарела.

Такая ошибка вылетает если появляются новые версии установленных модулей. После обновления (инсталляции заново) указанного модуля все работает нормально. Только если модулей больше 10 штук, приходится их обновлять (переинсталлировать) вручную. Подскажите, как сразу и махом обновить все.

Comment: мой ответ решает ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё достаточно просто:

`npm update --save` если у вас пакеты записаны в package.json в блок **dependencies**.

`npm update --save-dev` если у вас пакеты записаны в package.json в блок **devDependencies**.

При этом надо, чтобы у вас в package.json перед версией пакета был знак `^`, например `"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1"`

> https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update